# Getting Error while plotting a graph on Grafana dashboard : **"message": "Unable to call AWS API"**

Tags: grafana

Getting Error while plotting a graph on Grafana dashboard :

**"message": "Unable to call AWS API"**

Already successfully tested a data source and attached with metrics and and given other configuration properly like metric, state, dimensions.